# edge headless (--headless=new) is also used to set the desired window size ("--window-size=1920,1080")

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge, headless

With the new update in Edge browser, the headless has been renewed, it does not work with old codes. After the Headless is renewed, the windows size feature does not work directly. You can make it work with the codes below.

work to add this code ("force-device-scale-factor=0,5"),

worked for "--headless=new"

```
    WebDriver driver; /* start driver*/
    EdgeOptions options = new EdgeOptions();  /* add to EdgeOptions*/ 
    options.addArguments("--headless=new");                         
    options.addArguments("--window-size=1920,1080");
    options.addArguments("force-device-scale-factor=0,5");/* add to this row*/
    driver = new EdgeDriver(options); /* add options conteaner in Edgedriver*/
```

Comment: So is there a question for us for which you need a solution?

Comment: Are you simply sharing a solution with us? Do you have a question for us?

Comment: ı am sharing  simply a solution with you